# SciPy programming on CUDA cores

Tags: python, parallel-processing, scipy, gpu

Has somebody managed to apply SciPy functions on CUDA kernels? As far as I see from the literature, there is no explicit support of SciPy for GPU computing.

I would like to speed-up code with some SciPy.optimize functions by applying it on CUDA kernels. If somebody knows of any other library for nonlinear optimization that can be applied on CUDA GPUs, would very much appreciate sharing it here.

Answer (score 2):

[Numba](http://numba.pydata.org/) might be what you are looking for, it allows you to run python code on GPUs. Another good resource might be [this tutorial](https://developer.nvidia.com/how-to-cuda-python)

Comment: I am aware of Numba and it supports numpy, but no word about scipy

Answer (score 1):

I have right now a similar problem and came across CuPy. It supports CUDA and has an interface that allows a drop-in replacement for NumPy and SciPy.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32314826)

Answer (score -1):

Have run into similar problems and I am now using [tensorflow_probability's optimize capabilities](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/optimizer).  The biggest problem is that tensorflow ops often cannot be directly implemented from numpy functions, so there is a pretty steep learning curve.  But it is very fast once your code is written.